# offsetof macro in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#define offsetof(s,m) ((::size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
```

I've been looking for this code for several minutes and I still don't understand what the const char volatile reference thing is, it's giving me a headache.

```
#define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&(((s*)0)->m))
```

This one is pretty clear, does make sense and it works well, why is the other one being used by MSVC compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `s::m` is of a class type, it could overload `operator&`, so `&(((s*)0)->m)` would be the same as `(((s*)0)->m).operator&()`, which could do something unexpected.

To not use any custom `operator&`, it is cast to a `const volatile char&` first (which will have the same address). It needs to be both `const` and `volatile` because `s::m` might be const and/or volatile.

This is how [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) would have been implemented before C++11.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `offsetof` is in the standard library is that it cannot be written portably. So you’re looking at compiler-specific code. Don’t try to analyze it. Spend your time on more productive pursuits.

Comment: are you saying that the first example OP gives will not work on some compilers? Why not?

Comment: it's just a macro that I've been using for a while in OpenGL and I wanted to understand what it actually is, I don't usually analyze this kind of code. thanks for the advice!

Comment: @pm100 — it dereferences a null pointer, so the behavior of a program that does that is undefined.